# Can't open layout in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

It's my first time I have installed Android studio in my windows pc.I don't know much about this.iam a beginner.when I try to create a project I can't edit the layout (the activity_main.xml).it's always saying loading...
            Please help me....[This is the current screen when I open main_activity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpHqg.jpg)

Comment: Please check once gradle build completed

Comment: you need to wait until background tasks are done

Comment: You can take a screenshot from your screen using `snip & sketch` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is syncing your Project to Gradle files, you have to wait till it is complete, it may take a few minutes or longer depending on your device. Layout files don't usually work until Gradle sync completes and project successfully builds.